# FrameLayout in auto generated fragment layout xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am just curious that when we generate new fragment from android studio, why is there framelayout by default in auto generated layout file? Why not relative layout or any other layout?

Comment: I guess it is because FrameLayout the most lightweight layout available.

Comment: If it was `LinearLayout` you would ask "why is it LinearLayout?". It should be something, right? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because fragments are mostly developed using frames .. like whatsApp 3 fragments are build using frames and put into one activity.